# Google Charts with CSV file

Tags: javascript, html, csv, charts, google-visualization

I have the following html which works fine in producing a stacked column chart with Google Charts. I want to replace the static data in the html with an external csv file and am unable to get it to work.

Static Example (This works fine)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Day', 'Status A', 'Status B', 'Status C'],
          ['Monday', 10, 5, 3],
          ['Tuesday', 8, 2, 6],
          ['Wednesday', 6, 4, 10],
          ['Thursday', 12, 8, 4],
          ['Friday', 4, 12, 2],
          ['Saturday', 6, 4, 8],
          ['Sunday', 10, 6, 4]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Status Values by Day',
          isStacked: true
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have replaced the var data block with the following block of code to reference a 'data.csv' file.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Day');
data.addColumn('number', 'Status A');
data.addColumn('number', 'Status B');
data.addColumn('number', 'Status C');
data.load('data.csv', {'header': true, 'delimiter': ','});
```

The 'data.csv' file is formed as follows and I have it in the same folder as the html file.

```
Day,Status A,Status B,Status C
Monday,10,5,3
Tuesday,8,2,6
Wednesday,6,4,10
Thursday,12,8,4
Friday,4,12,2
Saturday,6,4,8
Sunday,10,6,4
```

When I open the html file it is blank, I'd like to know where I have gone wrong.
Thank you in advance for any help or pointers you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the folllowing way directly inside you HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(createChart);

      function createChart() {
        var chartData = new google.visualization.Query('data.csv');

        var options = {
            title: 'Custom chart',
            isStacked: true
        };

        chartData.send(function(response) {
          if (response.isError()) {
          console.error('Error message: ' + response.getMessage());
          return;
        }
        var dataTable = response.getDataTable();
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    });
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 440px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or as an option, you can replace script code with a reference to .js file where you put your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chartCreator.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer are you able to modify my html to include your suggested functions. I'm not sure what has to be removed or added in the correct place. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer for you. If you have any other question, please let me know, If this solution works for you please accept the answer by clicking green arrow.

Comment: Hi Valeriia, thank you so much for your input with this. I've used your modified html and I'm now getting this response instead of the chart.
You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView

Comment: Ahh yeah, you're right. Sorry for confusion. Anyway, I'm glad to help you.

Comment: So how do I correct the error, sorry about my dumb questions but I'm new to this?

Comment: I updated the answer. You are right. I didn't convert the data to DataTable format. Right now I send a request to retrieve data from csv and then use this returned DataTable object to draw a chart. Hope it works for you